# Gui Design Help - MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I need to design a Task Manager, not like windows task manager, but a more generic one.

like "i should take my kid to school" kind of task.

So, i need to design an appropriate scalable gui ? (in the future there might be hundreds of tasks)

Can someone suggest a place/app to look at ?

in addition, and on related subject :
I opened Mfc resource editor, and was trying to add columns to a list box, but couldn't find a way. is there a nice way to do it without writing code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the most excellent : ToDoList application by .dan.g. on CodeProject.

[ToDoList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx)

For the other question, I think you have to add columns in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to point you for generic GUI design, but I can help with the specific list box question. No, there's no way to add columns in the resource editor. Here's some crude code I recently did to make it easier:

```
void CMyDlg::AddColumn(LPCTSTR pszHeading, int iWidth, int nFormat)
{
    VERIFY(m_wndList.InsertColumn(m_iNextColumn, pszHeading, nFormat, iWidth, -1) == m_iNextColumn);
    ++m_iNextColumn;
}

void CMyDlg::AddItem()
{
    m_wndList.InsertItem(m_iItemCount, _T(""));
    m_iNextColumn = 0;
    ++m_iItemCount;
}

void CMyDlg::SetNextColumn(LPCTSTR pszText)
{
    m_wndList.SetItemText(m_iItemCount - 1, m_iNextColumn, pszText);
    ++m_iNextColumn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [one example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx) on CodeProject.

You make a list box multicolumn simply by clicking the "multicolumn" property. I'd guess what you really want is a list control in report mode, in which case you do need to add the second (and subsequent) columns using code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding columns to a listbox must be done in the code. For example, in your `InitDialog()`, or `OnCreate()`, or some other override, call `list.InsertColumn(...)` to add new columns. It's described very well in the MSDN help for `CListCtrl`.